# Adding to cart breaks fotorama on page reload

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, jquery, fotorama

Fotorama works normally until I click add to basket. After the page reloads this then shows collapsed (as per the image) and logs a couple of errors to console.[image: fotorama collapsed]

```
fotorama.js:99 Uncaught Fotorama requires jQuery 1.8 or later and will not run without it.Uncaught Fotorama requires jQuery 1.8 or later and will not run without it

gallery.js:290 Uncaught TypeError: settings.$elementF.fotorama is not a function
```

Comment: Actually jQuery is missing or you are using jQuery older than 1.8 So it is not working.

Comment: This definitely isn't true - as I can access it in console. Also it works until after I've added to cart and the page reloads.

Comment: Yes I faced same issue what you need to do put your fotorama code in the time out means it should run after 5 second after page loads 
Because in my case  also same issue it was not working in the first page load once i refresh it works 
I use time out so once page loads all javascript loads after that fotorama code executes so all worked fine.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're saying here, but please give a proper answer and some code if you have an explanation :)

Comment: Please post your javascript code here which you are using for slider.

Comment: I am getting similar issue, have you got any solution for this, please post here if you have any solution or patch for this.

Comment: any solution here please post and it would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved this issue by adding the following to my requirejs-config.js file:

```
var config = {
    shim: {
        'fotorama/fotorama': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

More info on shim configuration: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: which configuration would you use this shim in?

Comment: @ol'bobdole It goes in your theme or module's requirejs-config.js file. E.g. for your theme: `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme_name]/requirejs-config.js`. I've updated my answer will a full example.

Comment: any solution here please post and it would be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: The above answer didn't solve the issue.