# Magento 2 : settings.$elementF.fotorama is not a function

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images, fotorama-slider, fotorama

I installed **Magento 2.2.2** and getting issue with image gallery js. Product page images are not loading sometimes with below error

> **settings.$elementF.fotorama is not a function**

[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198572/adding-to-cart-breaks-fotorama-on-page-reload the keyword "sometimes" may mean some elements are not loaded when called, check require js in your design package.

Comment: Hi did you get a fix of that issue. I am facing the same problem after updating porto theme

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/138070)

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: @zedBlackbeard yes issue with the theme js load order. some js are not loaded so i just change the order and all work are smooth

Comment: @AjayPatel Could u pls describe the solution more because I am facing the same issue. It would be helpful

Comment: Did you found solution for this

Answer (score 0):

I had an external script that was causing this. I'm still not sure why, but in my case it was a script from Constant Contact (yours may be different).

Instead of including it in the header scripts, I moved it into a block (not sure if that did anything) and then I added an async tag to that script. That seems to have done it.

To troubleshoot, remove all of your third party scripts and see if that makes $fotorama run consistently. If it does, add the scripts back slowly until you figure out which one is breaking $fotorama.

Add an async tag to that script, and it should work.

Example

```
<script async> var _ctct_m = "<my cc id>"; </script>
```