# TypeError: settings.$elementF.fotorama is not a function

Tags: magento2, gallery-image, product-detail-page

I am facing issue of **TypeError: settings.$elementF.fotorama is not a function** sometime on product details page.

This question is duplicate of : [Adding to cart breaks fotorama on page reload](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198572/adding-to-cart-breaks-fotorama-on-page-reload) , [Magento 2 : settings.$elementF.fotorama is not a function](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229763/magento-2-settings-elementf-fotorama-is-not-a-function) etc

This question is asked before but still not found any proper solution for this. Please let me know answer if anyone solved this.

Comment: did you find solution? please add it if you have

Comment: Did you found any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

I had an external script that was causing this. I'm still not sure why, but in my case it was a script from Constant Contact (yours may be different).

Instead of including it in the header scripts, I moved it into a block (not sure if that did anything) and then I added an async tag to that script. That seems to have done it.

To troubleshoot, remove all of your third party scripts and see if that makes $fotorama run consistently. If it does, add the scripts back slowly until you figure out which one is breaking $fotorama.

Add an async tag to that script, and it should work.

Example

```
<script async> var _ctct_m = "<my cc id>"; </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 paths: {
        'fotorama/fotorama':'mage/gallery/gallery'
    },
    shim: {
        'fotorama/fotorama': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

i'm also facing the same issue, its working fine for me when i added below code :

path - **app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme_name]/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    shim: {
        'fotorama/fotorama': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Did the same but still facing the issue.

Comment: @anas I am facing the issue still too.

Comment: I am still facing the issue too, does anyone find a solution ?

Comment: Not work same error show