# Magento 2 Console Error Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento2.4, console, fotorama

I have Update Magento version 2.3.4 to 2.4 and now on the product page these errors are coming.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'migrateVersion' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Color' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
Uncaught Fotorama requires jQuery 1.8 or later and will not run without it.
Uncaught TypeError: settings.$elementF.fotorama is not a function
```

These errors are coming from this file.

```
stripes-custom/fr_FR/jquery/jquery-migrate.js
stripes-custom/fr_FR/jquery/ui-modules/effect.js
stripes-custom/fr_FR/js/lib/sticky-kit.js
stripes-custom/fr_FR/magnifier/magnifier.js
stripes-custom/fr_FR/fotorama/fotorama.js
stripes-custom/fr_FR/mage/gallery/gallery.js
```

To resolve this error I have tried this solution but not working.

[TypeError: settings.$elementF.fotorama is not a function](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265842/typeerror-settings-elementf-fotorama-is-not-a-function)

[How to change jQuery version in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150138/how-to-change-jquery-version-in-magento2)

[image: fotorama error]

I have tried by changing the theme from vendor to luma and blank but the console error was still remaining.

I have also updated the root lib folder with the latest Magento 2.4 lib folder but not work.

Anyone has a solution to this issue then please provide.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hello friends I found the issue.

jquery was conflicting

When I check in console jQuery was undefined

I have checked using require but jquery was not worked.

```
require(['jquery'],function($){
    console.log($.fn);
});
```

So I have a check-in page source and found that one jquery was added in the head section and it was coming from some custom extension.

So I have checked after removing this jquery and all error was resolved.

And I also found that all previous error $ and $.fn Undefine and fotorama was coming because of jquery.

Now all errors are resolved.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

had similar problem,

got error "effect-blind.js:35 Uncaught TypeError: $.effects.define is not a function" in page console.

used a custom template with an old view.xml, first i deactivated all modules then it was still not working but after I switched to default blank theme it was working.
so probably a theme problem